# APC & eAccelerator configuration

Tags: php, performance, optimization, apc, eaccelerator

Looks like I've done pretty stupid thing :) I'm trying to optimize performance so I've installed eAccelerator to cache and speed up PHP script executing. After that I've installed APC to store and retrive HTML pages from RAM memory (if I'm right about this). After benchmarking new PHP scripts with both eAccelerator and APC **enabled** at the same time I saw that reading HTML file from disk and displaying it was faster than displaying it from APC cache. Here's benchamrk results and PHP scripts. I need advice how to configure eAccelerator or APC to get better results.

```
ab -kc 500 -n 100000 http://0.0.0.0/html_disk.php
Requests per second:    14197.42 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       35.218 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.070 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          237307.67 [Kbytes/sec] received

ab -kc 500 -n 100000 http://0.0.0.0/html_apc.php
Requests per second:    11795.11 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       42.390 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       0.085 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests) 
Transfer rate:          197199.56 [Kbytes/sec] received
```

And scripts are simple as:
**html_disk.php**

```
$file = file_get_contents('page.html');
echo $file;
```

**html_apc.php**

```
if ($page = apc_fetch('page')) {
  echo 'APC!';
  echo $page;
} else {
  echo 'FILE!';
  $file = file_get_contents('page.html');
  echo $file;
  apc_add('page', $file, 120);
}
```

After first script loading HTML page should be loaded from shared memory right?

Comment: `$file = file_get_contents('page.html');
echo $file;` pretty pointless from a memory and speed perspective `readfile('page.html');` does both in one command, and faster and without the memory overheads

Comment: But if that's all your scripts are doing, there's nothing that either eAccelerator or APC can optimise

Comment: Not that familiar with eAccelator or APC, but I know that varnish can heavily speed up dynamic pages if configured right. Varnish acts as an caching HTTP reverse proxy

Comment: @Mark Baker That's sample script. I thought that reading HTML file stored in RAM memory should be faster than reading it from disk.

Comment: Except that you have an overhead of checking if it's in cache first.... APC cache is best used for caching the results of processor-expensive operations, not cheap operations like file_get_contents().... the biggest overhead with file_get_contents() (especially with smaller files) is the memory allocation and subsequent deallocation (which you'd eliminate completely if you used readfile() instead)

Comment: Caching only has performance value if the cost of checking/replenishing the cached data is less than the cost of generating the data to cache

Comment: OK. Thank you. After loading file I have some postprocessing code with decrypting I might cache those results. Thank you @MarkBaker